# Arduino Class Array Member

Tags: arrays, arduino

I am working on a Arduino Project and I have a class that has an array member, thats all fine but what I would like to do is be able to initialize the member array at initialization. So each time that the Class is used the array can be initialized at a variable length. Here is what I am trying but I keep getting compiler errors "invalid initializer for array member". I don't want to initialize each array to a max length, that would cause allot of wasted space.

### Header

```
class ClassA{

    int items[];

    ClassA(int Items[]);
};
```

### Source

```
ClassA::ClassA(int Items[]) : items(Items){

}
```

### And Initialize it like so:

```
ClassA obj1({1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
ClassA obj2({6, 7});
ClassA obj3({8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15});
```

Comment: I don't have the Arduino IDE available on this machine so can't test anything, but I wonder if it has something to do with how you are going about initialising the array.

Some languages initialise arrays like `datatype[] var_name` rather than `datatype var_name[]`

The following link may be useful: https://processing.org/reference/Array.html

Comment: @SimonShirley Excellent suggestion but no go... I get "error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token" when I try that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you come from other high-level languages (e.g. C# or Java), but... In C/C++ (and arduino, which is a child of these) you have two ways of declare an array:

1. statically allocated: `int Items[N_ELEM];`
2. dynamically allocated: `int *Items;`

There is no such thing as `int Items[];`, because you are not reserving the space at compile time.

Now, if you want to modify it at runtime, you have two ways.

1. use statically allocated arrays; in this case you will need to allocate it at compile time, so you have to enter a size big enough to fit the largest array.
2. use dinamically allocated arrays; in this case please implement also a destructor to free the memory.

Examples: method 1:

```
#define MAX_ITEMS 8 // Enter the largest value for the items length
class ClassA{
    int items[MAX_ITEMS];
    byte itemsLength;

    ClassA(int *Items, byte ItemsLength);
};


ClassA::ClassA(int *Items, byte ItemsLength){
    if (ItemsLength > MAX_ITEMS)
        itemsLength = MAX_ITEMS;
    else
        itemsLength = ItemsLength;
    byte i;
    for (i = 0; i < itemsLength; i++)
        items[i] = Items[i];
}


int array1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int array3[] = {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};

// Three ways to initialize it
ClassA obj1(array1, 5);
ClassA obj2({6, 7}, 2);
ClassA obj3(array3, sizeof(array3)/sizeof(int));
```

method 2a: using malloc

```
class ClassA{
    int *items;
    byte itemsLength;

    ClassA(int *Items, byte ItemsLength);
    ~ClassA();
};


ClassA::ClassA(int *Items, byte ItemsLength){
    itemsLength = ItemsLength;
    items = malloc(itemsLength * sizeof(int));
    byte i;
    for (i = 0; i < itemsLength; i++)
        items[i] = Items[i];
}

ClassA::~ClassA(){
    free items;
}


int array1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int array3[] = {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};

// Three ways to initialize it
ClassA obj1(array1, 5);
ClassA obj2({6, 7}, 2);
ClassA obj3(array3, sizeof(array3)/sizeof(int));
```

method 2b: Usable ONLY when the arrays are not deleted (i.e. you declare them as global static variables, not in a function)

```
class ClassA{
    int *items;
    byte itemsLength;

    ClassA(int *Items, byte ItemsLength);
};


ClassA::ClassA(int *Items, byte ItemsLength){
    // You just store the pointer, not the values
    // no need for a free
    itemsLength = ItemsLength;
    items = Items;
}


int array1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int array3[] = {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};

// Only two ways to initialize it
ClassA obj1(array1, 5);
ClassA obj2({6, 7}, 2); /* YOU CAN'T USE THIS */
ClassA obj3(array3, sizeof(array3)/sizeof(int));
```

method 2c: using c++ arrays

```
class ClassA{
    int *items;
    byte itemsLength;

    ClassA(int *Items, byte ItemsLength);
    ~ClassA();
};


ClassA::ClassA(int *Items, byte ItemsLength){
    itemsLength = ItemsLength;
    items = new int[itemsLength];
    byte i;
    for (i = 0; i < itemsLength; i++)
        items[i] = Items[i];
}

ClassA::~ClassA(){
    delete[] items;
}


int array1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int array3[] = {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};

// Three ways to initialize it
ClassA obj1(array1, 5);
ClassA obj2({6, 7}, 2);
ClassA obj3(array3, sizeof(array3)/sizeof(int));
```

MAYBE in this last case you can rdeuce the constructor to

```
ClassA::ClassA(int Items[]):items(Items)
{
}
```

but you'll have to test it, since I don't know if it'll work

Best regards

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. What I was trying to do is get away from having the "MAX_ITEMS" to initialize the array. If it is possible to create an array using int items[]={1, 2, 3} then it seems to me that you should be able to do the same thing in the constructor. Since I am running this on Arduino it was my impression that you wanted to avoid malloc like the plague due to fragmentation is this not right?

Comment: Well, `int items[]={1, 2, 3}` works because the compiler knows that `{1, 2, 3}` is an array of 3 elements, and so reserves 6 bytes (the size of an `int` is 2 bytes). When you declare it in a class the compiler doesn't know the size, so it can't reserve the space in advance: consequently you'll need to allocate it at runtime (with `malloc` or `new []`). This said, my favourite solution is the one with `MAX_ITEMS`, because I usually try to avoid allocating memory when using low resources uC. This is not so optimized, though, so if you need to create several different instances or you are running

Comment: out of memory, I'd go with method 2c. I never completely understood the "fragmentation issue", mostly because I tend not to use a lot of `malloc` and `free`: if I need to allocate the memory dinamically, I try to do it at startup and never deallocate it, instead of allocating and releasing and allocating again

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to do, use the constructor to define the size of the array in a round about sort of way. I think that the MAX_ITEMS is the safest way to go.

Answer (score 3):

```
template <size_t CAPACITY>
class MyDinamic
{
  public:
    int buffer[CAPACITY];
    MyDinamic(){}
};

MyDinamic<5> myDinamic;
main(){
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        myDinamic.buffer[i] = i;
    }
}
```

and you have _buffer with 5 items size